# Rails, Check if url already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple_form that has a bunch of urls that need to be inputted into the database.

Now i'm wanting to have a new record matches existing record page where you can compare the issues?

For instance. If a record has `google.com/search/stackoverflow`

And if someone types in the same url to be inputted into the same column name. It will alert the user stating that the field already exists and display the ID number of the field that exists. It then wont save the new field and will redirect the user back to the dashboard.

Heres the code i have at the moment.

Controller:

```
  def create
    create_params = params[:newevent].permit(:eventname, :eventshortdesc, :eventvenuename, :eventdesc, :eventdatetime, :eventimage, :1link, :2link, :3link, :4link, :5link, :6link, :event_type, :eventready, :eventcomplete)
    @newevent = Newevent.new(create_params)
    @newevent.save!
  end
```

view

```
<%= f.input :eventname, label: "Event Name", required: true %>
  <%= f.input :event_type %>
  <%= f.input :eventdesc, label: "Description", required: true  %>
  <%= f.input :eventshortdesc, label: "Short Description", required: true  %>
  <%= f.input :eventvenuename, label: "Venue Name / Location", required: true  %>
  <%= f.input :eventdatetime, type: "datetime", label: "Date Of Event: (Enter as YYYY-MM-DD)", required: true %>
  <%= f.input :eventimage, :label => "Image Name Here (exact)"%>
  <%= f.input :1link, label: "1 URL of Event" %>
  <%= f.input :2link, label: "2 URL of Event" %>
  <%= f.input :3link, label: "3 URL of Event" %>
  <%= f.input :4link, label: "4 URL of Event" %>
  <%= f.input :5link, label: "5 URL of Event" %>
  <%= f.input :6link, label: "6 URL of Event" %>
```

This is all i have at the moment.

Thanks for helping if you can.

Sam

Comment: Have you thought of the `uniqueness` validation ?

Comment: @Marwen I havent at all!!

Comment: @Marwen am i right in thinking all i need to do in my create method is add this?

validates :1link, 2link, uniqueness: true

Answer (score 0):

You just need a simple `uniqueness` validation.

```
class NewEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate_uniqueness_of :1link, :2link, :3link # whatever attribute you want to validate
end
```